# how to prevent the chinese input keyboard keyup and keydown event pass into react page

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am listening the keyup and keydown event in react function component like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
        window.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
            window.removeEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
        };
    }, [currInputIndex, inputValue]);
```

I have stored the history of textarea input, when user press key up and down, it could switch the user input history. Now I am facing a issue that when user using key up and down to select the input chinese words(because the chinese word will list all possible in the page and user could using key up and down to select which one is expect), it will alos trigger the key up and down events and change the textarea content that was unexpected action. I have tried to use this:

```
 event.preventDefault();
```

seems did not work. what should I do to avoid this issue? This is the keyup code:

```
const handleKeyUp = async (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
        if (event.key === 'ArrowUp') {
            event.preventDefault();
            const selected = inputValue && inputValue.length > 0 ? currInputIndex - 1 : currInputIndex;
            const stored = await getToIdb<Prompt>(selected);
            if (stored) {
                setInputValue(stored.name);
                setCurrInputIndex(selected);
            }
        }
    };
```

I have tried to found out what is the difference about chinese input key up and down and normal key up and down, the output keep that same:

```
console.log(event.target);
console.log(event.keyCode);
console.log(event.key);
```

I also tried using this:

```
onCompositionEnd={()=>setIsUserInputting(false)}
onCompositionStart={()=>setIsUserInputting(true)}
```

but this only trigger when switch between input method. when user stay on chinese input, the always stay true no matter user inputting words or not.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I give up handle the arrow up and down events global, just delete the global listening handle and move the events into keydown function like this:

```
const handleEnterKey = (e: any) => {
        if (e.nativeEvent.keyCode === 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            handleSend();
        }
        if (e.nativeEvent.keyCode === 38) {
            handleKeyUp();
        }
        if (e.nativeEvent.keyCode === 40) {
            handleKeyDown();
        }
    }
```

in the UI, bind the function like this:

```
<textarea
    id="talkInput"
    rows={1}
    value={inputValue}
    onChange={handleChatInputChange}
    onKeyDown={handleEnterKey}
    placeholder="Press enter to send" />
```

the chinese input up and down key press keycode will be 229, different with the normal keyup & keydown.